# Ncurses mvwaddch() isn't working before getch()

Tags: c++, ncurses

When I run this code, the two `for()` loops that draws the box isn't drawn. I've tested with gdb and it shows that the program does execute that two loops but somehow it isn't appearing. If the `while(true)` loop is removed, the box gets drawn. So, why?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <curses.h>
int main(){
    std::pair<int,int> csr_pos{1,1};
    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    curs_set(0);
    WINDOW *win = newwin(50,80,0,0);
    if(has_colors()){
        start_color();
        init_pair(1,COLOR_CYAN,COLOR_BLACK);
        init_pair(2,COLOR_RED,COLOR_BLACK);
        init_pair(3,COLOR_WHITE,COLOR_RED);
        init_pair(4,COLOR_YELLOW,COLOR_BLACK);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<80; i++){
        mvwaddch(win,0,i,'#');
        mvwaddch(win,49,i,'#');
        wrefresh(win);
    }
    for(int i = 1; i<49; i++){
        mvwaddch(win,i,0,'#');
        mvwaddch(win,i,79,'#');
        wrefresh(win);
    }
    mvwaddch(win,csr_pos.first,csr_pos.second,'@');
    while(true){
        int ch = getch();
        if(ch==KEY_LEFT){
            mvwaddch(win,csr_pos.first,csr_pos.second,' ');
            csr_pos.second--;
            mvwaddch(win,csr_pos.first,csr_pos.second,'@');
        }
        if(ch==KEY_RIGHT){
            mvwaddch(win,csr_pos.first,csr_pos.second,' ');
            csr_pos.second++;
            mvwaddch(win,csr_pos.first,csr_pos.second,'@');
        }
        wrefresh(win);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you have used `getch()` instead of `wgetch(win)`. Another thing to be mindful of is the size of the window you declare, which can cause a similar error.

Comment: now with `wgetch(win)` i see the map drawn, but now there  is no respond from keypresses.

Comment: @epixinvites Yeah you also need to call `keypad(win, TRUE)` instead of `keypad(stdscr, TRUE)`